# Division of two values in SQL Server. I get a weird result

Tags: sql-server, calculation

I'm quite a beginner with SQL, especially SQL-server and I need to devide two values. When I take the values Individually I get some value but when I divide these values manualy I don't get the same result I get in my query.

```
SELECT 

Count(IdPiece) AS NbPiece,

Sum(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(DATETIME,Ecriture.DateComptable,103),CONVERT(DATETIME,Ecriture.DateCreation,103))) as NbJours,

(Sum(DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(DATETIME,Ecriture.DateComptable,103),CONVERT(DATETIME,Ecriture.DateCreation,103)))) / (Count(IdPiece)) AS Moy_Saisie2,
```

I get the NbPiece, NbJours but the division doesn't give me the result I would get by dividing NbJours by NbPiece manually as you can see in the linked picture.
[Wrong values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/244pN.png)

What can I do to get the wanted result? I'm not really used to SQL and my knowledge is pretty minimal.

PS I should get something like 9.52 for my first division result (9 or 10 if its an integer maybe) instead I get 21 or 22.68 if I add "1.0 * (Sum(DATEDIFF...))

Comment: An INT divided by an INT will return an INT.   You can change the numerator to (Count(IdPiece)+0.0)   ... notice the +0.0

Answer (score 0):

That's integer division. Both operands of the division are integers, so you get an integer result: typically, `1/2` yields `0`, not `0.5`.

You can force a decimal result by adding a decimal operand to the operation, like so:

```
1.0 * SUM(
    DATEDIFF(
        day, 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, Ecriture.DateComptable, 103),
        CONVERT(DATETIME, Ecriture.DateCreation,  103)
    )
) / (Count(IdPiece) AS Moy_Saisie2,
```

Comment: I tried it, I get a different result but it's still not really what I was expecing to get. For example, as seen in the picture with the post I get "21 | 252 | 2400". With your method I get "22.68 |252|2400" but 2400 / 252 equals about 9.52